# Obtener clave valor de una matriz

Tags: php

Tengo esta matriz y no sé como obtener la clave/valor.

```
$respuesta = array(
    'metodo_pago' => "Efectivo",
    'total' => 16500.00,
    'estado' => "pendiente",
    'fecha_venta' => "2021-09-07 19:18:43",
    'seccion_id' => 1015484599958
);
```

Intente con `print_r($respuesta);` me muestra el array y con `var_dump($respuesta);` me dice que tipo de datos son, pero si quiero llegar a fecha de venta, no sé como obtener el valor.

Agradezco la ayuda!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

para tu ejempló, la forma de acceder al valor seria *Singular*:

```
echo $respuesta['fecha_venta'];
```

como lo indica la documentación: [Liink](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php)

el ejemplo#6:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tambien puedes implementar un `foreach`:

```
$respuesta = array(
    'metodo_pago' => "Efectivo",
    'total' => 16500.00,
    'estado' => "pendiente",
    'fecha_venta' => "2021-09-07 19:18:43",
    'seccion_id' => 1015484599958
);
              
foreach($respuesta as $key => $value){
    echo $key." => ".$value."<br>";
}
```

salida:

```
metodo_pago =>  Efectivo
total   =>  16500
estado  =>  pendiente
fecha_venta =>  2021-09-07 19:18:43
seccion_id  =>  1015484599958
```

tambien para acceder a todos los datos otra forma puede ser con `array_walk`:

```
<?php
$respuesta = array(
    'metodo_pago' => "Efectivo",
    'total' => 16500.00,
    'estado' => "pendiente",
    'fecha_venta' => "2021-09-07 19:18:43",
    'seccion_id' => 1015484599958
);

function test_print($elemento2, $clave)
{
    echo "$clave => $elemento2<br>";
}

//Depende de una funcion establecida:
array_walk($respuesta, 'test_print');

echo '<br>otra forma:<br>';

//Implmenta una funcion anonima:
array_walk($respuesta, function($elemento2, $clave) {
    echo "$clave => $elemento2<br>";
});
```

salida:

```
metodo_pago => Efectivo
total => 16500
estado => pendiente
fecha_venta => 2021-09-07 19:18:43
seccion_id => 1015484599958

otra forma:
metodo_pago => Efectivo
total => 16500
estado => pendiente
fecha_venta => 2021-09-07 19:18:43
seccion_id => 1015484599958
```

También es importante ya que hablamos de array que sepas lo siguiente:

***1. puede declarar de manera corta los array con `brakets []`:***

```
$respuesta = [
    'metodo_pago' => "Efectivo",
    'total' => 16500.00,
    'estado' => "pendiente",
    'fecha_venta' => "2021-09-07 19:18:43",
    'seccion_id' => 1015484599958
];
```

***2. puedes castear tus array en objetos:***

```
$respuesta = (object) [
    'metodo_pago' => "Efectivo",
    'total' => 16500.00,
    'estado' => "pendiente",
    'fecha_venta' => "2021-09-07 19:18:43",
    'seccion_id' => 1015484599958
];
```

después del casteo puedes acceder a sus propiedades de la siguiente forma:

```
echo $respuesta->fecha_venta; //usando la flecha y el indice
```

***3. implmentar `array_keys` y `array_value`:***

Ejemplo: https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b6WK

Documentación [array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-keys.php) y [array_value](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-values.php)

Código:

```
<?php
    echo '<pre>';
    $respuesta = [
        'metodo_pago' => "Efectivo",
        'total' => 16500.00,
        'estado' => "pendiente",
        'fecha_venta' => "2021-09-07 19:18:43",
        'seccion_id' => 1015484599958
    ];
    
    
    //quiero obtener solo una Lista de las llaves que tiene este array:
    
    $respuesta_key = array_keys($respuesta);
    
    echo var_export($respuesta_key,true).'<br>';
    
    //quiero obtener solo una Lista de los valores que tiene este array:
    
    $respuesta_values = array_values($respuesta);
    
    echo var_export($respuesta_values,true);
    echo '<pre>';
```

Comment: Gracias Francisco. No sabia que se podía crear un objeto de un array. Porque no es una practica habitual?

Comment: pocos lo saben y cuando programas orientado a objeto te saltas esto y creas otros tipos de objetos...

Comment: muchas gracias por el aporte...

Answer (score 3):

Puedes iterar los valores del array obteniendo su llave y valor

```
$respuesta = array(
    'metodo_pago' => "Efectivo",
    'total' => 16500.00,
    'estado' => "pendiente",
    'fecha_venta' => "2021-09-07 19:18:43",
    'seccion_id' => 1015484599958
);
              
foreach( $respuesta as $key => $value ){
    echo $key."\t=>\t".$value."\n";
}
```

salida:

```
metodo_pago =>  Efectivo
total   =>  16500
estado  =>  pendiente
fecha_venta =>  2021-09-07 19:18:43
seccion_id  =>  1015484599958
```

pero si deseas obtener un valor dentro del array, puedes hacer referencia a la llave y obtener su valor, por ejemplo para obtener el valor de "fecha_venta" dentro del array:

```
$respuesta = array(
    'metodo_pago' => "Efectivo",
    'total' => 16500.00,
    'estado' => "pendiente",
    'fecha_venta' => "2021-09-07 19:18:43",
    'seccion_id' => 1015484599958
);

echo $respuesta["fecha_venta"];
```

tendrìas como salida:

```
2021-09-07 19:18:43
```

---

Si deseas obtener todas las claves de un array o un subconjunto de claves de un array puedes usar [**array_keys()**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-keys.php):

```
$respuesta_key = array_keys($respuesta);
echo var_export($respuesta_key);
```

y puedes obtener el valor de una llave a partir de su indice, por ejemplo para el cuarto elemento:

```
$respuesta_key = array_keys($respuesta);
echo var_export($respuesta_key[3]);
```

Si deseas obtener todos los valores de un array puedes usar [**array_values()**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-values.php)

```
$respuesta_values = array_values($respuesta);
echo var_export($respuesta_values);
```

y puedes obtener el valor a partir de su indice, por ejemplo para el cuarto elemento:

```
$respuesta_values = array_values($respuesta); 
echo var_export($respuesta_values[3]);
```

Comment: Y utiliza `array_keys` y `array_values` es una alternativa? Cuando se puede utilizar?

Comment: cuando tienes obtener una lista de las llaves o valores que existe dentro de un array... luego decides que hacer con ella si la requieres.

Comment: @AntoniaHerrera puedes usarlos definiendo el indice del elemento para obtener su llave usando array_keys(): y su valor usando array_values(), agreguè esa informaciòn

Comment: Había pensado en recorrer el array con `foreach` pero no lo hice, al escuchar matris, creí que debía haber otro método. Muchas gracias!